# How can I convert an HTML string to PNG byte array in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, png

I am relatively new to Node.JS and have been researching how to convert HTML in a string (which is an HTML email template) to a PNG image in a byte array.  Reviewing through multiple npm packages, all reference how to convert an HTML file to a PNG file or if using an HTML string, they seek to extract a div, svg, or another element from within the HTML.  Does anyone have an example for this type of situation?

Comment: Have you tried [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webshot)?

Answer (score 0):

try this one: **html-convert**

Render a webpage and get the image as a stream.

> npm install html-convert

**example:**

```
var htmlConvert = require('html-convert'); 
var fs = require('fs');   
var convert = htmlConvert();   // convert a website url   
convert('http://example.com/my-site').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.png'));   // or as a transform stream  
fs.createReadStream('some-html-file.html')  
.pipe(convert())   
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.png'))
```